# split column pandas dataframe doesn't change

Tags: pandas

I am trying to split a column in four separated columns using pandas with the following code, however when I try to change the last one it replaces the column before, what is happening?

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['-6189794\t5712859\t4314.87772005053\t213402.703056687\n']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['a']
df

df['Min Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(0)
df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(1)
df['Min RMS'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(2)
df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(3)
```

See the image for results
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well your code is calling `df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(3)` and you previously called `df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(1)` so what are you expecting?

Comment: EdChum, thanks.... I didn't see it

Comment: If that was the problem then I suggest deleting the post as it's just a typo

Comment: If you suggest the post still remains in my profile? I like the suggestions in the answer below

Comment: Then you can change question - please some improvements... It is up to you.

Comment: ok..go ahead no problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need change last column name `Max Amp`, because you overwrite it.

So you can change column name, e.g. `Max Amp1`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ['-6189794\t5712859\t4314.87772005053\t213402.703056687\n']
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['a']
print df

df['Min Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(0)
df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(1)
df['Min RMS'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(2)
df['Max Amp1'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(3)
print df
                                                   a   Min Amp  Max Amp  \
0  -6189794\t5712859\t4314.87772005053\t213402.70...  -6189794  5712859   

            Min RMS            Max Amp1  
0  4314.87772005053  213402.703056687\n
```

But if you need strip `\n` from last column use [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['Min Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(0)
df['Max Amp'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(1)
df['Min RMS'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(2)
df['Max Amp1'] = df.a.str.split('\t').str.get(3).str.strip()
print df
                                                   a   Min Amp  Max Amp  \
0  -6189794\t5712859\t4314.87772005053\t213402.70...  -6189794  5712859   

            Min RMS          Max Amp1  
0  4314.87772005053  213402.703056687
```

Or you can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with parameter `expand=True`:

```
df[['Min Amp', 'Max Amp', 'Min RMS', 'Max Amp1']] = df.a.str.split('\t', expand=True)
df['Max Amp1'] = df['Max Amp1'].str.strip()
print df
                                                   a   Min Amp  Max Amp  \
0  -6189794\t5712859\t4314.87772005053\t213402.70...  -6189794  5712859   

            Min RMS          Max Amp1  
0  4314.87772005053  213402.703056687
```

If you have large DataFrame, you can use the fastest approach:

```
df[['Min Amp', 'Max Amp', 'Min RMS', 'Max Amp1']] = pd.DataFrame([ x.split('\t') for x in df.a.tolist() ])
df['Max Amp1'] = df['Max Amp1'].str.strip()
#if you need delete column a
df = df.drop('a', axis=1)
print df
    Min Amp  Max Amp           Min RMS          Max Amp1
0  -6189794  5712859  4314.87772005053  213402.703056687
```